# disable plus minus add button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spinner

My page have multiple add(+/-) cart button if one button has increment from out of three then all remaining button should be disabled to increment and decrements.

```
<div class="pull-right"><span class="desc_room_price">EUR 80.50</span>
    <span class="input-group __newbtn">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn  btn-number __minusbtn"  data-type="minus" data-field="hr_sec_b[1]">
                <span class="minus_btn_a"></span>
              </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="hr_sec_b[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-number __plusbtn" data-type="plus" data-field="hr_sec_b[1]">
                  <span class="plus_btn_a"></span>
              </button>
          </span>
      </span>
</div>

<div class="pull-right"><span class="desc_room_price">EUR 80.50</span>
    <span class="input-group __newbtn">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn  btn-number __minusbtn"  data-type="minus" data-field="hr_sec_b[1]">
                <span class="minus_btn_a"></span>
              </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="hr_sec_b[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-number __plusbtn" data-type="plus" data-field="hr_sec_b[1]">
                  <span class="plus_btn_a"></span>
              </button>
          </span>
      </span>
</div>

    $('.btn-number').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
        var type      = $(this).attr('data-type');
        var input = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']");
        var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            if(type == 'minus') {
                var minValue = parseInt(input.attr('min')); 
                if(!minValue) minValue = 0;
                if(currentVal > minValue) {
                    input.val(currentVal - 1).change();
                } 
                if(parseInt(input.val()) == minValue) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                }

            } else if(type == 'plus') {
                var maxValue = parseInt(input.attr('max'));
                if(!maxValue) maxValue = 9999999999999;
                if(currentVal < maxValue) {
                    input.val(currentVal + 1).change();
                }
                if(parseInt(input.val()) == maxValue) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                }

            }
        } else {
            input.val(0);
        }
    });
```

By default all button would be enabled.
What is problem, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are:

- Two inputs has identical name: `hr_sec_b[1]`
- All button has the same `data-field="hr_sec_b[1]"` value
- Missing buttons + and - labels.
- Fixed buttons disable/enable when min/max values are reached.

**[Working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/093Lt3d1/)**

**Corrected HTML**

```
<div class="pull-right"><span class="desc_room_price">EUR 80.50</span>
    <span class="input-group __newbtn">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn  btn-number __minusbtn"  data-type="minus" data-field="hr_sec_b[0]">
                <span class="minus_btn_a">-</span>
              </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="hr_sec_b[0]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-number __plusbtn" data-type="plus" data-field="hr_sec_b[0]">
                  <span class="plus_btn_a">+</span>
              </button>
          </span>
      </span>
</div>

<div class="pull-right"><span class="desc_room_price">EUR 80.50</span>
    <span class="input-group __newbtn">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn  btn-number __minusbtn"  data-type="minus" data-field="hr_sec_b[1]">
                <span class="minus_btn_a">-</span>
              </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="hr_sec_b[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-number __plusbtn" data-type="plus" data-field="hr_sec_b[1]">
                  <span class="plus_btn_a">+</span>
              </button>
          </span>
      </span>
</div>
```

**Corrected JavaScript**

```
$('.btn-number').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
    var type      = $(this).attr('data-type');
    var input = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']");
    var reverseInput = $("button[data-field='" + fieldName + "'][data-type!='" + type + "']");
    var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());

    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        if(type == 'minus') {
            $(reverseInput).attr('disabled', false);
            var minValue = parseInt(input.attr('min')); 
            if(!minValue) minValue = 0;
            if(currentVal > minValue) {
                input.val(currentVal - 1).change();
            } 
            if(parseInt(input.val()) == minValue) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }
        } else if(type == 'plus') {
            $(reverseInput).attr('disabled', false);
            var maxValue = parseInt(input.attr('max'));
            if(!maxValue) maxValue = 9999999999999;
            if(currentVal < maxValue) {
                input.val(currentVal + 1).change();
            }
            if(parseInt(input.val()) == maxValue) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    } else {
        input.val(0);
    }
});
```